# Searching for a program to evaluate linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, mathematica

I have a mechanical / geometrical system that is defined by certain equations. For some variables, I know that they are known, some of them are constant.
I would like to have a software (freeware) that allows me to evaluate the degrees of freedom (better: the positivity of the equation system) and that lets me play with some of the variables to see how they affect others.
I know that Matlab (with the Symbolic_Toolbox) would be capable of doing such things (Mathematica most probably as well), but since I am at work here and I don't have the license I would need a freeware solution.

EDIT:
I have the basic Matlab License. But I am not sure how to create an equation system and how to get information about how well it is determined without the symbolic toolbox.

EDIT 2:
What I am trying to solve:
[image: Measurement system]
I have a system that is running in X-Direction between two not ideal rails. Purpose of the system is to dertermine the track error of the two rails.
The system is spring-susbended on respectively two rolls on top and bottom which allows not only for the intended X-Movement but also a translation in Y direction and a rotation around any point within the rectangle defined by the four rolls. In addition to the four lengths that are measured here (L1 - L4) I have a relative X position given by a Sensor pointing in X direction (not marked).
In addition to that I have another set of four sensors that are on the same position of L1 - L4 a fixed distance above (Z direction).

To be honest, I think I don't even know what I exactly want myself. I am trying to get all the equations possible out of the system to see how underdetermined it is and what additional information (e.g. an angle sensor) the most useful would be.

Comment: GNU Octave is almost MATLAB. You might want to take a look at it's offerings along with the symbolic package.

Comment: You mean you have a linear system with free variables and you want to do...what exactly? It seems like whatever you want can probably be read off from the reduced echelon form, which is easily computed in Octave.

Comment: In its current state, this question is pretty vague. Why don't you actually tell us what you are solving?

Comment: @KingDuken Do you realize, that 2.8k€ for a single user professional license are far away from "freeware"?

Comment: Can you write what equations you know? (Math people are not going to want to translate your diagram into equations...)